# create database for OTA messages from XSDs (persisting OTA messages)

Tags: java, sql, xml, hibernate, xsd

I have to tackle a project with OTA (open travel alliance) messages. These xml messages have huge xsd s, and I am trying to find a way to resemble them in a database schema in an object relational manner, most probably PostgreSQL or MySQL.

So can anyone direct me to any technique that can help me, either in creating class models ( preferably Java ) out of xsd s and creating a storage for them in a db?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [JAXB 2.x](http://jaxb.java.net/), HyperJAXB2 (http://java.net/projects/hyperjaxb2/) or [HyperJAXB3](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home).